# Tracing storage media ejects and disconnects

Tags: windows-8, sd-card, event-log

I had a SD card that I kept permanently plugged into my laptop. Had, until I noticed it was missing this week. I don't know when exactly it fell out, the laptop may or may not have been in suspend at the time it happened. I'd like to find out when it went missing, so I know just where to go looking for it.

Are there any telltale events that might have been logged by my Windows 8.1 system? Maybe there is some kind of event for "this filesystem just disappeared"?
Anything outside the event viewer that is worth investigating?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks, but that other questions concerns USB (dis-)connects only

Comment: True enough (I was incorrectly thinking it was a USB flash drive in question).  anyhow, unfortunately removable device removals are not logged by Windows (at least not by default).  But you never know, someone may have an idea..

Answer (score 0):

run EventGhost (http://www.eventghost.org/downloads/), when a device is attached, removed you see an event on the left side.

[image: EventGhost]

This should include the Hardware ID of your SD card. Look if this helps you to debug your issue.